# javascriptから書き込んだcookieを読み取ることができない

Tags: javascript, cookie

javascriptからdocument.cookieを使って書き込んだcookieが読み取れません。
そのセッションのうちはconsole.log(document.cookie)で読み取ることができるのですが、ブラウザ(firefox)を立ち上げなおすと、console.log(document.cookie)の結果がempty stringになってしまいます。
max-ageを設定しており、開発者ツールからはcookieが保存されていることが確認できます。

cookieが保存されているにも関わらず、セッションが切り替わるとdocument.cookieから読めなくなってしまってお手上げ状態です。
解決策をご教授頂けると幸いです。

```
function cookieWrite(){
    document.cookie="cookie=test ; max-age=2592000";
}
function cookieRead(){
    console.log(document.cookie);
}
```

【2022/1/4追記】
使用しているブラウザはfirefox ver108.0.1です。
設定ではcookieを許可することになっており、一度は保存されます。
また、「firefoxを閉じたときにcookieとサイトデータを削除する」という項目からチェックを外しています。
ブラウザを立ち上げ直したあとも、開発者ツールのストレージ欄ではcookieが保存されていることになっているのですが、なぜかコードで読むことができません。

Comment: 「セッションが切り替わる」とは具体的にどういうことですか？　path を省略すると、クッキーがブラウザに保存される時そのページのディレクトリがパスに設定されると思いますがそのあたりはどうなっているのですか？

Comment: すみません、「セッションが切り替わる」というのは、1度ブラウザを閉じ、再度同じページを立ち上げることです。pathは省略しています。おっしゃる通り、HTMLのディレクトリがpathに設定されています。

Comment: 手元で確認してみました([コード](https://github.com/yukihane/stackoverflow-qa/blob/488dee9a92f0ae5b9f0a3a53a99a5bd9868d16c4/jaso93144/index.html))が再現しません。回答を得るためには、質問文に再現可能なサンプルコード([参考](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example))や実行環境の情報の追記が必要であるように思われます。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 「セッションが切り替わる」というのは、1度ブラウザを閉じ、再度同じページを立ち上げることです。

expires 属性を指定してないのですよね。その場合、クッキーはブラウザのメモリにしか保持されません。従って、ブラウザを閉じればクッキーは消えます。

Fiddler などのキャプチャツールを使って要求・応答をキャプチャして、ヘッダにクッキーが含まれているか調べてみてはいかがですか？

**【2022/1/4 10：28 追記】**

> ブラウザ(firefox)を立ち上げなおすと、console.log(document.cookie)の結果がempty stringになってしまいます。

同じコードで、Windows 10 の Firefox 108.0.1 で試してみましたが再現しません。期待通り以下のようになります。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

質問者さんのやり方の問題では？　設定で「Firefox を閉じたとき Cookie とサイトデータを削除する(C)」にチェックが入っているとか？

Comment: ご回答頂きありがとうございます。max-age属性を指定しているので、有効期限は正しく反映されています。ブラウザーを立ち上げた時に、コンソールからCookieを確認することができるのに、document.cookieで拾えないのです。ヘッダにCookieが含まれていないということなのでしょうか

Comment: > max-age属性を指定しているので、有効期限は正しく反映されています。=> そうですか、失礼しました。ではクッキーを設定する際 path=/ を追加してみたらどうなりますか？

Comment: > ヘッダにCookieが含まれていないということなのでしょうか => クッキーが設定されていれば Web サーバーに要求を出す際クッキーは要求ヘッダに含まれて Web サーバーに送信されます。それを確認してみてはということです。

Comment: 承知しました。もう一度トライしてみます。ありがとうございました！